# Inserting pair in map

Tags: dictionary, tree, insert

For a map,

```
map<int,pair<int,int>>m;
```

The below line worked

```
m[level]=pair<int,int>(h,root->data);       //root is a pointer to a node in tree
```

But the below didn't

```
m.insert(pair<int,pair<int,int>>(level,(h,root->data)));
```

Why?

Comment: Does it not compile or does it not work?

Comment: @pesuww It doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding C++ tag to the thread. Use std::make_pair for making pairs. And it's not really recommended to use `using namespace std;` [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

```
m.insert(std::make_pair(level, std::make_pair(h, root->data)))
```